# Load html in pywebview with arguments

Tags: python, webview

I want to load html code in pywebview (desmos API), but I have to include arguments in the function load_html, but I'm getting errors when running. I have the following code:

```
import webview

def load_html(window,userExpr,vars):
    htmlCode = 'html code' + userExpr + 'more html code' + vars + 'even more html code'
    window.load_html(htmlCode)

userExpr = "y=x^2"
vars = [-10,10]
window = webview.create_window("Graph", width=1210, height=820)
webview.start(load_html,window,userExpr,vars)
```

I want it to load the html code with the included arguments, but when I run the program I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    webview.start(load_html,window,vars)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\webview\__init__.py", line 71, in start
    original_localization.update(localization)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start()` expect only one argument.

For many arguments use list or tuple - `[window, userExpr, vars]`.

```
import webview

def load_html(window, userExpr, vars):
    print(window, userExpr, vars)
    htmlCode = 'html code' + userExpr + 'more html code' + str(vars) + 'even more html code'
    window.load_html(htmlCode)

userExpr = "y=x^2"
vars = [-10,10]
window = webview.create_window("Graph", width=1210, height=820)
webview.start(load_html, [window, userExpr, vars] )
```

Other places are for different options - see [documentation for start()](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/guide/api.html#webview-start)

```
webview.start(func=None, args=None, localization={}, http_server=False, gui=None, debug=False)
```